element.iterchildren() in python xml.etree.ElementTree?
I was wondering if python's own Element Tree API has any native equivalent to lxml's iterchildren and iterdescendants?
From what I can see from the docs the main way to iterate over all the children of an element is to use the iter function which first yields the element itself before yielding any of the children.
I can always hack them in myself like so:
def iterchildren(root_element:Element) -> Iterator[Element]:
"""Only get direct children from an Element"""
    children:list[Element] = root_element.findall("*")
    for child in children:
        yield child

def iterdescendants(root_element:Element) -> Iterator[Element]:
"""Get all descendants from an element using recursion"""
    children:list[Element] = root_element.findall("*")
    for child in children:
        yield child
        if len(child) != 0:
            for grandchild in iterdescendants(child):
                yield grandchild

which would give:
a = fromstring("""<root><child1><subchild1><subsubchild1></subsubchild1></subchild1></child1><child2></child2></root>""")

for child in a.iter():
    print(child.tag)
# root <- I don't want this to happen
# child1
# subchild1
# subsubchild1
# child2

for child in iterchildren(a):
    print(child.tag)
# child1
# child2

for child in iterdescendants(a):
    print(child.tag)
# child1
# subchild1
# subsubchild1
# child2

But I was wondering if there's a "built-in" way to do this like you can in lxml as I'm not sure of the performance cost of the above solution.
Any pointers regarding the above code is also appreciated if you find something I did wrong.

Do you really need iterchildren? Instead of for child in iterchildren(a), just use for child in a.

I guess it's just personal preference that I prefer to call a generator function to iterate over the children or descendants of an element instead of just treating it as a list (or potentially a list of lists if the children have grandchildren)
also, thanks for pointing the error in the print statement, fixed it.
